# Object Filters in Softlayer in Java

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to make a call using softlayer client in java , i am able to make normal and straight forward calls even able to apply the object mask.
But not getting a way to apply object filter in my service or in my api call using softlayer client.
I am trying to get the invoices available between two dates by passing dates as part of object filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry objectFilters are not supported yet for the Softlayer JAva Client see https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/30