# SOFTLAYER REST API Wrong result using objectFilter

Tags: java, json, rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the SOFTLAYER REST API in order to get the virtual machine list then select one of the results and get more details only about the selected machine.

I used this URL to get the machine details by hostname but i get all the machines as result and not the one i selected

URL :

```html
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,fullyQualifiedDomainName,provisionDate,powerState,operatingSystem[id,passwords[password,username],softwareDescription[longDescription]]]&objectFilter={"hostname":{"operation":"SLRAMONT02"}}
```

What should i do the get the wright result?

I used python with the same url and I get the expected result but after a debug I found that python is converting the JSON to XML and using the SOAP API.

I'm not planning to use the python API but the JAVA. Can I make the same request using JAVA API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically was answered here: [Softlayer filtering not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361347/softlayer-filtering-not-working).

On your case you need to use following filter:

```
objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation":"SLRAMONT02"}}}
```

Also I recommend to review: [How to use object filter with softlayer rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186972/how-to-use-object-filter-with-softlayer-rest-api)

Unfortunately object-filters is not supported yet by [Softlayer-Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java) API, this is commented here:
[Object Filters in Softlayer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832019/object-filters-in-softlayer-in-java)
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/30

If you really need to use object-filters in Java, you can try by using RESTFul, there are some RESTful examples in the following links.

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/